# Restricted cubic spline with Complex survey data(regression fitted by survey::svycoxph, survey:: svyglm, etc.)

Tags: r, survey, splines

Recently I am working with complex survey data.
I use the `survey` package to analyze the data.
I fitted cox proportional hazard model by`svycoxph` and find some potential non-linear relationship between the variable and outcome.

So I try to plot the model by restricted cubic spline.
`rms::cph` and `survival::pspline` are two ways I used in general cox regression(which is not complex sampling). But both these two ways don't work in `svycoxph` fitted model.

Here are my codes in general cox model

1.I try`rms`package

```
library(rms)
library(survival)
data(pbc,package = 'survival')
data<-pbc
attach(data)
ddist <- datadist(data)
options(datadist='ddist')
k <- with(data, quantile(age,c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75 )))
model<-cph(Surv(time,status>0)~rcs(age,k),data=data)
plot(rms::Predict(model,age,ref.zero=T, fun=exp))
```

and I can get such a plot.

[image]

**However, rms::Predict doesn't support the model fitted by `svycoxph`.**

2.And I have another try using `survival::pspline` which works in the following situation

```
library(survival)
data(pbc,package = 'survival')
data<-pbc
model<-coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(age, df = 4), data = df)
termplot(model, term = 1, se = T,plot = T)
```

And the following plot was shown.

[image]

**Unfortunately,svycoxph does not support penalised terms, either.**

So, Is there any package that can help me plot the restricted cubic spline with model fitted by `svycoxph`?
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: There will be a new version of the `rms` package on CRAN around 2022-10-22 that will support the use of `rcs()` in non-`rms` contexts.   This is accomplished by making the general `predict()` find the knot locations.

Comment: While you wait for the update to `rms`, you might consider trying the `ns()` function in the standard `splines` package, which also handles restricted cubic splines. I don't find its defaults to be as sensible as those for `rcs()` and you don't get a simple linear coefficient from it, but as the function has a long history in R and doesn't involve penalization it might work.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for updating the package. I hope this topic is still worth discussing. I try the latest version which was released in May 2023. However, ```rms::Predict``` still does not support the model fitted by ```svycoxph```. If any process is needed before Predict the model? Thank you.

Comment: When using `svycoxph` you have to use its basic `predict` method.